# Pass the output of a chained command to grep or append to file

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, output

I'm trying to kill and restart pulseaudio in verbose mode, I need to search in the output. I tried to use the pipe to grep the output. After that failed I tried to append the output to a file. I'm doing something wrong.

The kill and start command is

```
pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v | grep conf
(pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v) > 'aout.txt'
pulseaudio -k && (pulseaudio -v > 'aout.txt')
```

It still just displays the output as it is in the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

*Note that I prefer to grep than to append to file.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to redirect the commands' standard error as well e.g. (using bash command grouping, so as to capture *both* commands error streams with a single redirect)

```
{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v ; } 2>&1 | grep 'conf'
```

or using the shorthand `|&` operator

```
{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v ; } |& grep 'conf'
```

---

To redirect to a file

```
{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v ; } > aout.txt 2>&1
```

(note the order of redirections) or its semantic equivalent

```
{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v ; } &> aout.txt 2>&1
```

See the `REDIRECTION` section of `man bash`

Comment: yes that works for grep  but the append isn't working. I'm trying `{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v; } 2>&1>'aout.txt'`

Comment: `{ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v; }>'aout.txt'  2>&1` got it! thank you very much!!! cheers :D